# Can I point an XAMPP localhost to external directories on the same network?

Tags: php, networking, xampp, virtual, host

I'm sorry if the title is unclear, its tough for me to word this question effectively.

If I have XAMPP running on one computer that is connected to a network with a shared drive, and I want my root directory to be a directory located on the shared network drive, is this possible?

Currently, I am just using the htdocs folder within XAMPP, but the end goal is to make the root directory a folder on the public network where files are frequently added to so that I can dynamically upload these files to an intranet index using PHP.

I have heard of virtual hosts, and I think that might be the right direction to look into, but I'm not sure if it will be able to accomplish this.

Alternatively, I could install XAMPP on the server itself, but I want to avoid doing this.

Comment: Not a programming question, more suited for other forums. Please, read [how to ask useful questions aka MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no such thing as a folder in a network. There might be a resource in the network that can be accessed to use a folder. That is something you can do, sure. You only need to mount that resource into your systems local file system hierarchy and then you can access is with all the means the apache http server offers.